# Variable Assignment in Bash Script

Tags: bash

I have seen one syntax in bash script for variable assignment. probably i am not getting what is use of it.

Syntax is :

```
VarName=()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bash` shell has simple variables and one-dimensional array variables. That one is simply creating an empty array.

You can see the effect in the following transcript which creates arrays of varying sizes and shows you their size:

```
pax> x=(1 2 3 4 5) ; echo ${#x[@]}
5
pax> x=(1) ; echo ${#x[@]}
1
pax> x=() ; echo ${#x[@]}
0
```

Comment: @Axit, I'd prefer you to accept my answer because it was *right* rather than quick but, since it's both right *and* quick, I'll take it :-)

Comment: i first checked that it was right or not. and then i commented like this. as Stackoverflow only allows to accept answer after 15 mins. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the documentation. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters

```
VarName=1
VarName="two"
```